# Why setTimeout code blocked?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

```
function test(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var now=new Date();
    while((new Date()).getTime() < now.getTime()+5000){ }
    console.log('p')
  }, 0);
}

test();
test(); //it takes 10 seconds,the second test function runs after the first finished.
```

can somebody explain to me how it works?

Comment: JavaScript is not "multi-threaded"; the functions execute in serial, not parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because, whenever you pass a `function` inside of `setTimeout` and call it, the passed function will be pushed into the `callBack` queue based on the supplied delay in milliseconds. The functions inside of callBack queue will be executed one by one in the order they have pushed. So here in your case, you are blocking the code flow of `function` which is present inside of `callBack` queue, by running a `while` loop. Hence the second call of `test` is taking 10 seconds to execute.

```
test(); //call 1
callBack queue ---->  [function(){ while(){} }]

test(); //call 2
callBack queue ---->  [function(){ while(){} }, function(){ while(){} }]
```

Note: Call back queue will start its execution when there is nothing in the call stack to execute.

Best read for this, [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Comment: So,the code in the `while(){}` won't be excuted at the same time?

Comment: @lx1412 Yeah, The functions in the callBack queue will be executed as a normal execution of functions inside a normal array. one by one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non-blocking implementation you have to replace your synchronous `while` loop with asynchronous recursion:

```js
function test(x){
  setTimeout(function loop(now) {
    (new Date()).getTime() < now.getTime()+2000
     ? setTimeout(loop, 0, now)
     : console.log('p', x);
  },0, new Date())
}

test(1);
test(2);
```